# How to get Plural form from Singular form?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization, inflector

I want to get plural of the given noun. I have tried JAVA INFLECTOR. But it has very poor accuracy for nouns not following the regular rules.

*Examples from JAVA INFLECTOR:*

1. paparazzo -> paparazzos
2. criterion -> criterions
3. tooth -> tooths
4. thief -> thiefs
5. loaf -> loafs

Stanford coreNLP lemmatizer is very good at plural to singular conversion. It takes care of many exceptional cases. As stated below:

*Plural to singular from STANFORD LEMMATIZER*:

1. vertices -> vertex
2. spectra -> spectrum
3. alumni -> alumnus
4. criteria -> criterion
5. thieves -> thief
6. geese -> goose
7. fungi -> fungus
8. loaves -> loaf.

But the problem is I don't know how to get plural from given singular using Stanford CoreNLP. The lemmatizer gives singular from plural.

So, basically I want to get plural from singular nouns using STANFORD NLP.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Just reminds me of the very first thing I tried to program with a friend. I don't have Stanford NLP experience unfortunately but like to see an answer to this. Is your first set of examples the output from Java Inflector? "Tooth -> Tooths", can see why you're not happy with that. Criteria is the only correct one.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes, it is output of java inflector. And second set of examples is from stanford corenlp lemmatizer. I just edited it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt actually Criteria is my typing mistake.LOL. It gave criterion->criterions. I edited that too.

Answer (score -3):

If you can harness javascript, I created a lightweight javascript for this. Very easy to use:

```
pluralizer.run('goose') --> 'geese'
pluralizer.run('deer') --> 'deer'
pluralizer.run('can') --> 'cans'
```

https://github.com/rhroyston/pluralizer-js